# Append a key-value pair to a dict automatically

Tags: python, dictionary, translation

how can I add key-value pairs to a dictionary automatically? for example I have a very long file of one word in Greek, and the translation in English (these are separated by a ";"): this is repeated for many lines and I would like to put each line (formed by "Greek;translation") in the dictionary.
I show you an example:

```
αἰτέω;ask;beg
αἰτία;responsibility
αἰτιάομαι;accuse;censure
```

And I want:

```
dict = {'αἰτέω': 'ask, beg', 'αἰτία': 'responsibility', 'αἰτιάομαι': 'accuse, censure'}
```

Another example can be:

```
a bow;un inchino
a cloaklet;un mantello
a coaxing;un lusinghiero
```

And I want:

```
dict = {'a bow': 'un inchino', 'a cloaklet': 'un mantello', 'a coaxing': 'un 
        lusinghiero'}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Show what you tried already as properly formatted code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from pprint import pprint

lines = """αἰτέω;ask;beg
αἰτία;responsibility
αἰτιάομαι;accuse;censure
a bow;un inchino
a cloaklet;un mantello
a coaxing;un lusinghiero"""

d = {
    line.split(";")[0] : ", ".join(line.split(";")[1:])
    for line in lines.splitlines()
}

pprint(d)
```

Result:

```py
{'a bow': 'un inchino',
 'a cloaklet': 'un mantello',
 'a coaxing': 'un lusinghiero',
 'αἰτέω': 'ask, beg',
 'αἰτία': 'responsibility',
 'αἰτιάομαι': 'accuse, censure'}
```

Comment: How do yoy use 'for line in lines.splitlines()'? because it gaves me error. I have adapted your suggestion but I can't figure out how to integrate this last part as well. I did this:            with open('filename', 'r', encoding = "utf-8") as testo:
    for line in testo:
        d = {line.split(";")[0] : ", ".join(line.split(";")[1:])}
        
        print(d)

Comment: I just ran this snippet. Maybe try to insert this line in the 2nd line of the file: # -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

Comment: sorry and if I have: a handle;una maniglia?

Comment: Please clarify by providing the new value of lines and the expected output.

Comment: The code remains unchanged (I updated the snippet).

Comment: idk but for example it gaves me: {'a': ' ', 'bow': 'un inchino'}

Comment: This is probably because you use .split() instead of split(";") / splitlines(). This is the main difference between my solution and Wasif Hasan's one.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `dict` comprehension don't use `dict` as variable name:

```
s='''αἰτέω;ask;beg
αἰτία;responsibility
αἰτιάομαι;accuse;censure'''
mydict = {x.split(';')[0]: ', '.join(x.split(';')[1:])for x in s.split()}
```

Comment: sorry and if I have: a handle;una maniglia?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way is to just split by '\n' and split ';' in for

```
text= 'αἰτέω;ask;beg\nαἰτία;responsibility\nαἰτιάομαι;accuse;censure'.split('\n')
result = dict()
for t in text:
     t = t.split(';')
     result[t[0]]  = t[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a csv file, you eventually mean this?

```
def csv_dict_list(variables_file):
    reader = csv.DictReader(open(variables_file, 'rb'))
    dict_list = []
    for line in reader:
        dict_list.append(line)
    return dict_list
```